# Calculating administrator's portion

Tags: python, math

I have calculated portions for each relative, child and parent. I have also calculated portion for administrator which is $39691.350000000006, however the correct amount should be $39854.0. I don't know how the leftover for administrator after all the parties is calculated. Could someone give a *clue*?

**Instruction:**

1. Firstly, the administrator gets a quarter of one percent of the inheritance plus whatever is left over (nobody receives fractions of dollars, just whole dollars).
2. Each non-child, non-parent relative gets one portion
3. Each child get 100 times the amount of each relative
4. Each parent get twice as much as each child

Code:

```
import random

total_inheritance = 1587654
administrator_percent = 0.025
parents = 2
children = 3
relatives = 10
```

**The correct output should be:**

```
Relatives get: $2180.0 each
Children get: $218000.0 each
Parents get: $436000.0 each
Administrator gets: $39854.0 each
```

Comment: I don't see any calculations? How are we supposed to debug if you don't show us how you calculated the wrong amount?

Comment: Without showing code you don't have a valid stackoverflow question.

Comment: Your "correct" numbers don't make sense: 39854.0 is already a bit more than 2.51% (not 0.25%) of the total, so it's already out by a factor of 10 (plus a bit).  Either the numbers are wrong, or there's some information missing from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick (ran under python3):

```
total_inheritance = 1587654
administrator_percent = 0.025
parents = 2
children = 3
relatives = 10

# Lets subtract out the administrator's portion
initial_admin_amount = administrator_percent * total_inheritance
total_inheritance -= initial_admin_amount

# calculate portions
portions = relatives + 100 * children + 200 * parents
amount_per_portion = total_inheritance / portions

relatives_portion = amount_per_portion // 1
children_portion = 100 * relatives_portion // 1
parents_portion = 2 * children_portion // 1

# add the initial  amount back in
admin_portion = total_inheritance + initial_admin_amount
# subtract out all the handouts
admin_portion -= relatives * relatives_portion
admin_portion -= children * children_portion
admin_portion -= parents * parents_portion

print("Relatives get: ${} each".format(relatives_portion))
print("Children get: ${} each".format(children_portion))
print("Parents get: ${} each".format(parents_portion))
print("Administrator gets: ${} each".format(admin_portion))
```

The trick is that `// 1` bit, which cuts off the trailing decimals. It is the integer division operator in python. So 5 // 2 = 2, 4 // 2 = 2, 1.5 // 1 = 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation of floats. You can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

As a workaround, you can do the following conversion: `print("%.2f" % result_float)` or you can do rounding by other means.

Comment: You can't round `39691.350000000006` to `39854.0`

Comment: You are right, I can not. I'm not rounding 39691.35 to 39854.0, I'm cutting off the trailing decimals which appear on floating point operations as mentioned on the link I provided. The original code may have different issues (losing some decimals in the middle while calculating, etc). I also wonder what `import random` adds up there.